# Форма обратной связи на github.io. Не приходит письмо с Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html5

У меня есть небольшое портфолио на github.io. И там есть простая форма обратной связи. Ajax как бы работает, так как функция done выполняется успешно. Но письмо не приходит на емейл. 
Буду очень благодарен за ответ.
Вот ссылка https://sh-vasyl.github.io

// HTML

```
<form class="form">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Ваш Е-майл" required>
    <textarea type="text" name="message" placeholder="Комментарий к заказу</textarea>
<button class="btn">Отправить заявку</button>
</form>
```

// JS

```
$(".form").submit(function() {
    var ths = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "mail.php",
        data: $(this).serialize()
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
        setTimeout(function() {
            ths.trigger("reset");
        }, 1000);
    });
    return false;
});
```

// Php

```
$recepient = "up.vasyl@gmail.com";
$sitename = "Моё Портфолио";

$name = trim($_GET["name"]);
$email = trim($_GET["email"]);
$text = trim($_GET["message"]);

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
$message = "Имя: $name \nЕмайл: $email \nТекст: $text";

mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в ответ на запрос (странно, что `GET`, а не `POST`) возвращаете содержимое PHP файла (GitHub вряд-ли выполнит произвольный код у себя на сервере).
Помимо всего прочего сделайте лучше обработку результата через `.success()`/`.error()` или обрабатываете статус ответа. Сейчас, даже если сервер лежит, ничего никуда не поедет, но пользователю вернется, что все ОК.

Answer (score 1):

На github.io php файлы не выполняются.

Естественно, что письма не будут отправляться.